# SQLModel / SQLAlchemy Problem with model mapper while querying in empty tables

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

Update: This is not a problem with Relationships in SQLModel! See the answer below for more explanation!

I am relatively new to SQLModel and SQLAlchemy, however I can't figure out this one.

Basically the problem: Using SQLite as a database I have a `configs` table that holds 3 UUID's for different sub-configs (server, user and business) all in their separate tables. I am declaring the models as follows:

```py
class ServerConfigBase(SQLModel):
    """Base Server Configuration."""

    address: str
    port: int
    app_configs: List["Config"] = Relationship(back_populates="server")

class ServerConfig(ServerConfigBase, table=True):
    """Configuration model describing network communication fields"""

    id: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

class BusinessConfigBase(SQLModel):
    """Base Business Configuration."""
    ...
    app_configs: List["Config"] = Relationship(back_populates="business")


class BusinessConfig(BusinessConfigBase, table=True):
    """Configuration model describing Business related fields"""

    id: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

class UserConfigBase(SQLModel):
    """Base User Configuration."""

    name: str
    app_configs: List["Config"] = Relationship(back_populates="user")


class UserConfig(UserConfigBase, table=True):
    """Configuration model describing user settable fields"""

    id: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

class ConfigBase(SQLModel):
    """Base Configuration."""

    server: ServerConfig = Relationship(back_populates="app_configs")
    server_conf_id: UUID = Field(foreign_key=ServerConfig.id)
    business: BusinessConfig = Relationship(back_populates="app_configs")
    business_conf_id: UUID = Field(foreign_key=BusinessConfig.id)
    user: UserConfig = Relationship(back_populates="app_configs")
    user_conf_id: UUID = Field(foreign_key=UserConfig.id)
    random_list_of_string_field: List[Dict] = Field(sa_column=Column(JSON[List[Dict]]))

class Config(ConfigBase, table=True):
    """Table configuration."""

    id: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    active: bool = False
```

When I check on startup if the active config exists via `session.exec(select(Config).where(Config.active == True)).first()` (in case theres a db file already populated) I get the following error:

```bash
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper mapped class Config->config, SQL expression or this Session.
```

Same happens if I were to just select all on the table. Not sure why my model is not mapping correctly.
Stack trace:

```bash
  File "/Users/somaf/repos/api/src/api/controllers/config.py", line 91, in read_configs
    return session.exec(select(Config)).all()
  File "/Users/somaf/repos/api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlmodel/orm/session.py", line 60, in exec
    results = super().execute(
  File "/Users/somaf/repos/api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1705, in execute
    bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
  File "/Users/somaf/repos/api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2154, in get_bind
    raise sa_exc.UnboundExecutionError(
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper mapped class Config->config, SQL expression or this Session.
```

I didn't forget to create the tables and the session is set up correctly as well.
Any help would be much appreciated and sorry if this is a nooby question.

#### Edit 07.01.2024

As asked here's how the `create_engine` function is called:

```py
engine = create_engine(
            "sqlite://",
            connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
            poolclass=StaticPool
        )
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

These two lines are from the main.py where a `lifespan` function will do this and other setup related operations. The create_engine call is going to be different after this bug is squashed to check for existing files and worst case default to an empty in-mem database. And sorry for the late reply!

Comment: But it works if you manually insert rows in the SQLite file?

Comment: Couldn't get to the point to insert yet because it's a refactor and old files have a different schema (and I deleted the dev one so It's not trying to access it)

Comment: Ok, I just sounded like that from your title. How are you setting up the engine? Are you calling `create_engine`?

Comment: @MatsLindh Added it in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem and it was to do with the `engine` and `session` as the comments also suggested. I originally suspected the `Relationship` to be the problem because that was the major part of the refactor and not the tidying of imports and control flow. The problem was that we originally imported the engine from a `database.py` file. Before the refactor `engine` was declared as follows:

```py
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../../../config", job_name="robin_app"):
    config = compose(config_name="default")

engine = create_database_engine(config)
```

In the refactor I set it to be initially `None` before calling the `create_db_and_tables` from the `main.py` file where its' value gets updated. The problem was that even though I updated the value, the imported reference is still the older `None` value. In debugger it shows:

[image]

By making `engine` private and using a getter solved the issue. Thanks again for all to have commented and sorry for not giving an update sooner.